# How to solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined error in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is my script to get the parameter from URL and store it in the input field.
I am able to console.log the parameters but not able to store in the input field
please help.
My javascript code.

```
function getNavUrl() {  
    return window.location.search.replace("?", "");
};
function getParameters(url) {   
    var params = {};
    url = url.toLowerCase();
    url = url.split('&');   
    var length = url.length;
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
        var prop = url[i].slice(0, url[i].search('='));
        var value = url[i].slice(url[i].search('=')).replace('=', '');
        params[prop] = value;    }
    return params;     
};

var a =getParameters(getNavUrl());
var username=a.username;
var password=a.password;
alert(password);
document.getElementById('username').value = username;
```

My input field.

```
<input id='username' name='user'  placeholder='mqtt user' value='' ><br/>
<input id='userpassword' name='password' placeholder='mqtt password' value='' >
```

The error i am getting.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at yolo.html?username=somename&password=123:31
```

Comment: change `document.getElementsById('username').value` to `document.getElementById('username').value`

Comment: Thank you for the reply I did same but in alert, I am getting the value but not inside the input field

Comment: What you getting in `alert(username);` ?

Comment: The parameter which I am sending through URL

Comment: do you have window onload event?

Comment: No, I don't have

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add document load event:

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     var a =getParameters(getNavUrl());
     var username=a.username;
     var password=a.password;
     alert(password);
     document.getElementById('username').value = username;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.getElementById('username').value = username;
```

getElementById isnstead of getElementsById

Comment: Thank you for the reply I did same but in alert, I am getting the value but not inside the input field

Comment: are you sure you have these inputs in DOM when you're trying to set a value? https://jsfiddle.net/x3p6tf8e/2/

Comment: maybe you need $( document ).ready...
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code
});

Answer (score 0):

```js
var username='username'
var password='passwo';
//alert(password);
document.getElementById('username').value = username;
```

```html
<input id='username' name='user'  placeholder='mqtt user' value='' ><br/>
<input id='userpassword' name='password' placeholder='mqtt password' value='' >
```

There are `getElementById` but `getElementsById` (the difference is the char **s**)

Comment: Thank you for the reply I did same but in alert, I am getting the value but not inside the input field

Comment: @NithishPK why you accept this answer if this didn't work for you?

Comment: @Rainmax93 to accept your answer there was no right mark and the second-best answer was eric answer that's the reason

Comment: @NithishPK: Don't accept an answer just for the sake of it. That gives future visitors the wrong impression.